# How is a quanto priced?

Tags: fx

How would one price a derivative denominated in EUR that pays in USD?

Comment: Does [this paper](http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/FX_Quanto.pdf) help?

Comment: nice paper to explain the basic concepts.

Comment: @chrisaycock: thank you I will have a look, my stochastic calculus is quite bad so I may struggle a bit.